# Batch: Is there a way to set it up so that if at any point in time any variable equals something it does a command?

Tags: batch-file

Basically what my title says.
Is there a way to set it up so that if at any point in time any variable equals something it does a command?

Comment: Which operating system are you talking about?

Comment: You can use `/?` after a command to get help for that command. It's obvious that you made no attempt to find a solution, so look at the output of `if /?` which will tell you exactly what you want to know.

Comment: @SomethingDark it's a valid question for someone unfamiliar with the batch scripting language.  @OP unfortunately, the batch language has no event handlers like JavaScript's `onchange` or `MutationObserver`.  You could spawn a helper script that loops until the variable changes, but that would only work if you don't use `setlocal`, which I would discourage.  Not using `setlocal` is generally considered [bad practice](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).  Perhaps it might help to be specific about *why* you want to watch a variable for change, and show some code demonstrating what you hope to do.

Comment: @rojo - your spawned process cannot see changes that occur in the parent processes environment.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you hope to accomplish, it's difficult to know what will work for you.  However, I have thought of a potential solution.  For the variable you want to watch, instead of simply calling `set "varname=value"`, you could `call :set varname value`, then use a subroutine to perform the watching.  Here's an example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /a foo = 10, loop = 1

:loop
call :set foo "%foo% * %loop%"
set /a loop += 1
goto loop


:: End main script / begin :set subroutine
:set <var_to_set> <expression>
setlocal
set /a test = %~2

:: watch for %foo% to have a value greater than 50000
if %test% geq 50000 (
    echo %~1 equals %test%.  Press any key to exit.
    >NUL pause
    exit
)

endlocal & set "%~1=%test%"
goto :EOF
```

Of course this is much less efficient than a `for /L` loop, but it should demonstrate the proof of concept.  The `:set` subroutine effectively watches `%foo%` to reach a value, then performs an action.

See [this page on `endlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) and [this page on DOS functions](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) for more examples of using subroutines to set variable values.